# How to plot the Cubic Spline generated from the CubicSpline method in the scipy package in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, interpolation, cubic-spline

I'm trying to generate a plot for the cubic spline generated between the points

```
#y-coordinate 
    v_max = [0.07313751514675049,
         0.0931375151467517,
         0.11313751514675259,
         0.13313751514675398,
         0.1531375151467546,
         0.17313751514676343,
         0.19313751514676608,
         0.2131375151467626,
         0.23313751514675923,
         0.2531375151467538]
#x-coodinate
t = [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0, 11.0, 13.0, 15.0, 17.0, 19.0]
```

I used Cubic Spline method from the scipy package for cubic spline interpolation

```
cs = CubicSpline(t, v_max, bc_type='natural')
```

How do I get a list of points on the spline for the time period np.arange(0, 20, 0.1)?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the example given in the [`CubicSpline` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html), you can call the cubic spline as if it is a function, providing the coordinates where you want to evaluate the cubic spline as an argument.

```
cs = CubicSpline(t, v_max, bc_type='natural')

t_interp = np.arange(0, 20, 0.1)
v_interp = cs(t_interp)
```

The variables `t_interp` and `v_interp` are now both numpy arrays with shape `(200,)`.

[image: interpolated data]

Your data can be represented as a straight line, which is reflected by the generated interpolation.